# Why do users look at the worst comments first?

Tags: comments, ratings

A product may have 98% of positive comments and 2% of bad comments, instead of looking what most people liked something, most users jump directly to the few worst comments, by definition less representative.

Why the hell users do that (including me)

[image]

Comment: The answers you get to this question are likely to be mainly opinion-based ...as is my suggestion: We want to understand the relevance of the bad reviews in order to count or discount them in our own evaluation of a product or service. You'll sometimes see bad reviews that relate to the lateness of delivery, or the fact that the product doesn't do something that it was never intended to do - these are effectively 'noise' in the decision making process and I know that I like to discount these and understand the real flaws before I start reading how 'wonderful' something might be.

Comment: "most users jump directly to the few worst comments" What makes you think this?

I think your question is based on a fallacy really. I have seen no evidence that users DO do this. Maybe they do, maybe they don't, but without evidence that this is even an issue it's not going to be very easy to answer.

Comment: indeed i do not have metrics about that, it is just an observation i have made while test sessions on a non representative number of user; i hoped to find some explanation about the way users analyse the comments

Answer (score 1):

Extract from this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/wired-success/201411/why-we-love-bad-news) :

> The answer may lie in the work of evolutionary psychologists and
>   neuroscientists.  Humans seek out news of dramatic, negative events.
>   These experts say that our brains evolved in a hunter-gatherer
>   environment where anything novel or dramatic had to be attended to
>   immediately for survival. So while we no longer defend ourselves
>   against saber-toothed tigers, our brains have not caught up.

Also from the wiki article about [negativity bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias#Attention) :

> A number of studies have suggested that negativity is essentially an
>   attention magnet. For example, when tasked with forming an impression
>   of presented target individuals, participants spent longer looking at
>   negative photographs than they did looking at positive photographs.
>   Similarly, participants registered more eye blinks when studying
>   negative words than positive words (blinking rate has been positively
>   linked to cognitive activity).